# Delete a batch of docs using admin SDK and callable cloud function in most similar way to client SDK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an array of docs ids that I want to delete in using a cloud function, my code looks like the following :

```js
//If the user decieds on deleting his account forever we need to make sure we wont have any thing left inside of db after this !!

// incoming payload array of 3 docs
data = {array : ['a302-5e9c8ae97b3b','92c8d309-090d','a302-5e932c8ae97b3b']}

export const deleteClients = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    // declare batch
    const batch = db.batch();

    // set
    data.arr.forEach((doc: string) => {
      batch.delete(db.collection('Data'), doc);
    });

    // commit 
    await batch.commit();
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  return null;
});
```

I am getting a syntax error on batch.delete how to pass the right arguments in to the batch delete to reference that doc I want to submit for deletion before commit ?

Comment: Hello can you share your `package.json` content as well as how you define the `db` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

- `data.arr.forEach()` cannot work wince your data object contains one element with the key `array` and not the key `arr`.
- You are mixing up the syntax of the JS SDK v9 and the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node). See the write batch Admin SDK syntax [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js_2).
- You need to send back some data to the client when all the asynchronous work is complete, to [correctly terminate your CF](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).
- You do `return null;` AFTER the try/catch block: this means that, in most of the cases, your Cloud Function will be terminated before asynchronous work is complete (see the link above)

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
const db = admin.firestore();

const data = {array : ['a302-5e9c8ae97b3b','92c8d309-090d','a302-5e932c8ae97b3b']};

export const deleteClients = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    
    const batch = db.batch();
    const parentCollection = db.collection('Data')
   
    data.array.forEach((docId) => {   
      batch.delete(parentCollection.doc(docId));
    });

    // commit 
    await batch.commit();
    
    return {result: 'success'} // IMPORTANT, see explanations above
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    // IMPORTANT See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
  }
  
});
```

Comment: thanks for the great explanation I have been working with only front-end SDK I need to learn more, now it makes way more sense.

Comment: there is yet a small question what if the    batch.delete(parentCollection.doc(docId)); errors yet we are returning {result: 'success'} before that catch ? will it give a false positive in that case ? should the return success be after the catch conforming that every thing went ok ?

Comment: If there is one error in the batch it will be catched by the catch block. "Should the return success be after the catch conforming that every thing went ok ?" => Absolutely not! This would finish the Cloud Fucntion, see the doc referred to in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Delete takes a single param, the doc ref of the doc to be deleted.

```
data.arr.forEach((docId: string) => {
  batch.delete(doc(db, "Data", docId));
});
```

Comment: sadly I am getting deleteClients doc is not a function.